# Counter that shows click of the button and stores that data with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have a form that, when clicked, redirects to a page. However, I want that in addition, when the click happens, it activates a counter and that this counter keeps showing up even after the page is closed.

I tried to do this with localstorage, I can store the first click, but I can't display or store the others

This is my code

```js
document.getElementById('contadorInscritos').value = localstorage.contadorInscritos;

var salvarClique = function() {
  var clickcount = document.getElementById('contadorInscritos').value;
  localStorage.setItem('contadorInscritos', 'contadorInscritos');
}   

document.onclick = salvarClique

let contadorInscritos = 0;  
function clickbutton(){  
  contadorInscritos ++;
  document.querySelector('#contadorInscritos').innerHTML = contadorInscritos * 5 + ' novos inscritos';
}
```

```html
<form id="forms_layout">
  <div>
    <div class="email labels" id="email_label_mail">
      <input class="input_labels" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" type="email" size="20" required />
      <span class="placeholder_input" data-placeholder="E-mail"></span>
    </div>
    <span id="email_message_error" class="message_error">Email inválido.</span>

    <div class="first_name labels" id="email_label_name">
      <input class="input_labels" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" required />
      <span class="placeholder_input" data-placeholder="Nome"></span>
    </div>
    <span id="first_name_message_error" class="message_error">Nome obrigatório.</span>

    <div class="phone labels" id="email_label_phone">
      <input title="Insira um formato de telefone válido" class="input_labels" id="phone" minlength="15" maxlength="15" name="phone" size="20" pattern="(d{2})d{5}-d{4}" />
      <span class="placeholder_input" data-placeholder="Celular"></span>
    </div>
    <span id="phone_message_error" class="message_error">Formato de Telefone inválido.</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="connect_icon py-1">
    <button id="button_layout" class="button_layout" type="button" onclick="clickbutton()">
      <b id="lblBotao">QUERO ME INSCREVER</b>
      <div id="divSpiner" class="spinner-border" role="status" style="display: none;">
      <span class="sr-only">Enviando...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="send__icon">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    </button>
  </div>

  <p style="color: white; font-weight: 600; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <span id="contadorInscritos"> novos inscritos</span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- When fetching data from localStorage you need to use the getItem
  method.
- When you use setItem, you are passing the second argument as a string, rather than as a variable.
- I suggest you keep the counter element separate.

  ```
   // save counter element to a variable:
   var counterElement = document.getElementById('contadorInscritos');

   // fetch contadorInscritos from localStorage
   var contadorInscritos = localStorage.getItem('contadorInscritos');

   // in case there is no value already in localStorage:
   if (!contadorInscritos) { contadorInscritos = 0; }

   // update the dom with the vale fetched from storage:
   counterElement.innerText = contadorInscritos * 5;

   // save contadorInscritos to localStorage whenever document is clicked
   var salvarClique = function (event) {
       localStorage.setItem('contadorInscritos', contadorInscritos);
   };

   document.onclick = salvarClique;

   // handle button clicks:
   function clickbutton() {
       contadorInscritos++;
       counterElement.innerHTML = contadorInscritos * 5;
   }
  ```